# Disable Warning Sign

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

Is there any way to stop this warning sign from popping up in Microsoft Access 2007-2013 via VBA method? I have tried (DoCmd.SetWarnings False) and (Application.DisplayAlerts = false)

Apparently Both of the method didn't work out at all.
Any Help will be greatly appreciated.

[image: Confirm]

Comment: @horney_D_Clown

Comment: @Homey_D_Clown_IT Sorry about that, ok the logic at the backend is to copy the file and paste it somewhere using the objFSO.CopyFile method however in order to do that I need to retain the original file name which will show me the link shown above which is rather irritating as I'm trying to copy the file not replace it. So in conclusion, I need something that could execute a VBA code and simply turn this warning thing off.

Comment: I just added an answer for you with the source, etc. so give it a shot when you get a chance, this should resolve your problem.

Comment: @Homey_D_Clown_IT Thank you so much!! :D The problem is solved

Comment: Anytime, glad to help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [CopyFile Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265015(v=vs.60).aspx) and consider using the `overwrite` argument to pass to the function to tell it that if the file exist, then overwrite it and do not prompt.

> ### [Visual Basic for Applications Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265015(v=vs.60).aspx)
>
> **CopyFile Method**
>
> **Syntax**
>
> object.**CopyFile** source, destination[, overwrite]
>
> The **CopyFile** method syntax has these parts:
>
> - **Part:** *overwrite*
>
>   - **Description:** Optional. **Boolean** value that indicates if existing files are to be overwritten. If **True**, files are
>       overwritten; if **False**, they are not. The default is **True**. Note
>       that **CopyFile** will fail if destination has the read-only attribute
>       set, regardless of the value of *overwrite*.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> Wildcard characters can only be used in the last path component of the
>   source argument. For example, you can use:
>
> ```
> FileSystemObject.CopyFile "c:\mydocuments\letters\*.doc", "c:\tempfolder\"
> ```
>
> But you can't use:
>
> ```
> FileSystemObject.CopyFile "c:\mydocuments\*\R1???97.xls", "c:\tempfolder"
> ```
>
> If source contains wildcard characters or destination ends with a path
>   separator (), it is assumed that destination is an existing folder in
>   which to copy matching files. Otherwise, destination is assumed to be
>   the name of a file to create. In either case, three things can happen
>   when an individual file is copied.
>
> - If destination does not exist, source gets copied. This is the usual    case.
> - If destination is an existing file, an error occurs if overwrite is    **False**. Otherwise, an attempt is made to copy source over the existing    file.
> - If destination is a directory, an error occurs.
>
> An error also occurs if a source using wildcard characters doesn't
>   match any files. The **CopyFile** method stops on the first error it
>   encounters. No attempt is made to roll back or undo any changes made
>   before an error occurs.

<sub>[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265015(v=vs.60).aspx)</sub>